# How to avoid double horizontal scroll bar in firefox

Tags: c#, javascript, css

HI,

Iam facing with issue with ff not in IE.Double horizontal scroll bars are getting displayed when the content exceeds.Please help me how to fix this.Do we need to change anything in css

Comment: As @SLaks says, you need to provide a lot more detail before anyone can give you genuine help on this. Can you show us the HTML code that has the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra `overflow: auto` in an inner element.

You can receive no further help until you provide much more detail.

Comment: @Spudley can you give me one example for controlling this kind of issue when the content exceeds. i CAN'T get u the html code right now.

Comment: Use Firebug to see what is scrolling.